# Load more recyclerview Items on click of "more" button with url

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using retrofit to showing recyclerview items. At first only two of them is visible but on clicking of "show more" button, I am trying to load rest of the items with api.

my approach is to add more items with a url but not able to figure out if i am going in a correct way or not.

I am able to show starting 2 items and from back end , I am getting a url in "nextComments" tag. Passing this url as a parameter in api calling method. Trying to figure out the next approach

```
Api.getReplies(nextUrl.toString())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result ->
                if (!result.results.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    nextUrl = result.next.toString()


                    //-------what should be here-----//?
                    replyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            },
            { error ->
                println(error)
            })
```

The items are expected to add in recyclerview, when i click on show more

Comment: add the items to the dataset before notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @JoachimHaglund any sample code which can help me for adding data with url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how your adapter code looks like, but here is a generic example:

```
//get the new items from backend
var more_objects = await MyWebService.GetMoreObjects (indexKey);
// add the items to the adapter
_adapter.appendObjects(more_objects);
_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
```

appendObjects in the adapter:

```
    public void appendObjects (List<MyObj> obj)
    {
        foreach (var o in obj) {
            data.Add (o);
        }
    }
```

appendObject in kotlin

```
fun appendObjects(obj: List<MyObj>) {
    obj.forEach { 
        data.Add (it); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you show the append method in kotlin. That would be helpful, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: added kotlin verion to answer